# Multiple Base64 image within 1 array causes overriding

Tags: javascript, arrays, base64

Let's say I want to upload 2 images to an ajax, I will send them using this format

> ```
>  { "base64StringName:" : "[ {"1": "base64_1"}, {"2" : "base64_2"} ]"}
> ```

So its an object that contains an array of objects of base64 strings
To do so, I will need to create an array and inside this array, I will push json objects into it.

Here is my code for this:

```
        <script>
        var test ='';
        var imageArray =[];
       var imageObject ={};
$('#inputFileToLoad').on('change', function(){    
  imageArray.length = 0;
 fileCount = this.files.length;
   for(i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
  var file = document.querySelector('#inputFileToLoad').files[i];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
    test = reader.result.split(',')[1];
    console.log(test);
    imageObject[i] = test;
     imageArray.push(imageObject);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     alert('Error: ', error);
   };
}

});
$('#inputFileToLoadButton').on('click', function(){
  console.log(imageArray);
$.ajax({

                url:"some url",
                method:"POST",
                data: {
                  "base64String": imageArray
                }
                    ,success: function () {
                        swal("Success!","Upload Finished!","success");
                        //add redirect!
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        swal("Error",jqXHR.responseText, "error");
                      }                    
             });
});    
    </script>
```

However, I encounter a problem, my first object inside the array somehow gets overwritten.
it becomes

> ```
>  { "base64StringName:" : "[ {"1": "base64_2"}, {"2" : "base64_2"} ]"}
> ```

Also when i printed out the first base64 encoded file at `console.log(test);` it is undefined, but when i printed out the second base64 encoded file, it prints the second file only.

Comment: That is because you making changes to the same "imageObject" object. Once you push the "imageObject", create a new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
var test = '';
var imageArray = [];
var imageObject;
$('#inputFileToLoad').on('change', function() {
  imageArray.length = 0;
  fileCount = this.files.length;
  for (i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
    debugger;
    var file = document.querySelector('#inputFileToLoad').files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
      test = this.result.split(',')[1];
      imageObject = {};
      imageObject[index] = test;
      imageArray.push(imageObject);
    }.bind({
      index: i
    });
    reader.onerror = function(error) {
      alert('Error: ', error);
    };
  }

});
```